# How to solve Importing issue in wordpress 3.3.2?

Tags: wordpress

How can I solve this problem when I ma trying to import posts in wordpress 3.3.2 ??

> The export file could not be found at
>   /home/pixl/public_html/wp-content/uploads/shutter.xml_.txt. It is
>   likely that this was caused by a permissions problem.

Although the permissions for the uploads folder are : 777

!!

Answer (score 1):

i found different solution of this problem just install backupwordpressdb plugin and make backup of your wordpress and download that zip file again import that zip file into your next wordpress site and import that zip file.

may be this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check the permission of your date based folder: uploads/2012/06/ My Wordpress import saves data there.

Comment: the uploads folder is empty !

Comment: Stupid question: can you upload an image? (to check if your uploads work at all)

Comment: I can upload image !! .. u should be more polite

Answer (score 0):

Mine was an isolated use case... but just posting here in case someone else struggles.

The wordpress importer does not play well with the Media Cloud plugin (and I would assume other plugins that modify where uploads are stored).

Disabling the media cloud plugin fixed this problem for me. Try disabling all your plugins and running the importer again (as I should have done... I know better).

Good luck!